# Is it possible to hide "Console was cleared" message using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am using

```
console.clear()
```

to clear the console. But it shows

> Console was cleared

message in the console. Is it possible to keep my console completely clean?

Comment: Don't log anything in the first place? Or rewrite `console.log = () => {}`

Comment: I'm doubtful, I wouldn't be surprised if it wasn't possible while staying on the same page. If you navigated to the page again, it would clear the console if the browser isn't set to preserve logs

Comment: Why are you worried about what's in the console in the first place

Comment: @JeremyThille That doesn't seem to work, I can still see the log.

Comment: Sounds a bit like an XY problem. You really should explain why that message is a problem for you.